# Arrivals based on database

Tags: anylogic

I am trying to retrieve arrival rates from a excel spreadsheet in my model but I don't have the option to select the specific row and column i want. How can I ensure that a specific cell is chosen? (For example i want the value 5 corresponding to "limeConveyor" row and "red" column.

[This is the sample spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMq0F.png)

[This is the properties window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2FN5.png)

Thank you in advance for your help! :)

Edit 1:

I am currently unable to select "red" from the
[dropdown list of value column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2b3uM.png). Is my program bugged or something?

Comment: you are doing it.. but you forgot to put the value (which will be "red" in your case) and you are choosing blueConveyor, you can choose "limeConveyor"... You just have to add the value, and it should work fine.

Comment: Hmm i am unable to see the options for that in the value column. Am i missing something here?

Comment: your database doesn't fit the values.. you are using the wrong database maybe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe to clarify Felipe's reply: I suspect your dbase table is not setup correctly and doesn't match your xls screenshot.

First, load your spreadsheet into an AnyLogic dbase table using the wizard. It should then look like this (note the column properties: the column type is important):

[image]

Now in your source, you can easily load the required column-row combination and the valuer-dropdown allows you to select "red" if you want:
[image]

You can find the example model that I used for the screens [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/m9zthc18cmu26m9/Model13.zip?dl=0), hope this helps.

Comment: PS: don't worry about that weird "al_id" column: this is normally not visible and you don't need to take it into account

Comment: ok cool i managed to do it when i created a new model. Might be cause of something wrong about how I setup that previous model. Thank you! @Benjamin